# Combining Cypher and GraphQL unable to traverse relationship node

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql, cypher, grandstack

I am new to Neo4j and have been learning for the past few days about using GraphQL with Neo4j through Grandstack. I've been working through [this Guide](https://grandstack.io/docs/graphql-relationship-types.html) and [this Repository](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-js/blob/master/example/apollo-server/movies-schema.js) working on setting up schemes. I've been working off of the sample [neo4j movie database](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/) Im attempting to do a basic query where I select the movie by rating using a cypher query as shown below. How ever when testing in the browser I am receiving the following error. Any idea how to fix this or what I am doing wrong thank you

```
   const typeDefs = `
type Movie {
    title: String
    tagLine: String
    released: Int 
    reviews: [Reviewed] 
}
type Reviewed @relation(name: "REVIEWED"){
    from: Person
    to: Movie
    summary: String
    rating: String
}
type Person {
    name: String
    born: Int
    actedIn: [Movie] @relation(name: "ACTED_IN",direction:"OUT")
}

type Query {
    Movie(title: String ,released: Int, first: Int, offset: Int): [Movie]
    ReviewsByScore(score: Int): [Reviewed] @cypher(statement: "MATCH()-[r:REVIEWED]-() WHERE r.rating >= $score RETURN r;")
}
`;

const schema = neo4jgraphql.makeAugmentedSchema({ typeDefs });
```

In the browser I run the following query

```
{
  ReviewsByScore(score: 100) {
    rating
    summary
    to{
      title
    }
  }
}
```

and receive the following error.

> {   "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined",
>         "locations": [
>           {
>             "line": 2,
>             "column": 3
>           }
>         ],
>         "path": [
>           "ReviewsByScore"
>         ],
>         "extensions": {
>           "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
>           "exception": {
>             "stacktrace": [
>               "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined",
>               "    at getRelationTypeDirective (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test
>   Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/utils.js:763:7)",
>               "    at buildCypherSelection (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test
>   Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/selections.js:184:64)",
>               "    at recurse (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/selections.js:87:33)",
>               "    at buildCypherSelection (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test
>   Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/selections.js:176:12)",
>               "    at recurse (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/selections.js:87:33)",
>               "    at buildCypherSelection (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test
>   Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/selections.js:176:12)",
>               "    at customQuery (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/translate.js:575:68)",
>               "    at translateQuery (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/translate.js:518:12)",
>               "    at cypherQuery (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/index.js:146:40)",
>               "    at _callee$ (/Users/a123456/Desktop/Neo4j Test Javascript/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/index.js:73:31)"
>             ]
>           }
>         }
>       }   ],   "data": {
>       "ReviewsByScore": null   } }

Comment: In your cypher statement for the `ReviewsByScore` query, can you try to specify the direction of the relationship : `MATCH()-[r:REVIEWED]->()` ?

Comment: Having exactly the same trouble. Could you find a proper solution?